# How to display PHLivePhotoView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, phlivephoto

I'm working on a basic app for live photos and try to build user interface on SwiftUI. However, I don't understand how to display Live Photos properly. Is it possible to incorporate PHLivePhotoView into SwiftUI?

Comment: It is a UIView, so use UIViewRepresentable wrapper.

Comment: Omg, it's almost one-liner. Now I see that it was a lame question. However, I spent an hour googling with no success so I'll leave it here. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299030/asperi) mentioned, UIViewRepresentable wrapper is a way to go:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

struct LivePhotoView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var livephoto: PHLivePhoto

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PHLivePhotoView {
        return PHLivePhotoView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ lpView: PHLivePhotoView, context: Context) {
        lpView.livePhoto = livephoto
    }
}
```